# How to insert a value into a nested table without losing data in that table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I insert new data into an existing row's nested table? For example, I have defined

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE businessTableForCategories AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(128);
/

CREATE TABLE Category (
name                    VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
businesses              businessTableForCategories
) NESTED TABLE businesses STORE AS categoryBusinessTable;
```

Say in Category there is an entry with `name = 'Restaurant'` and `businesses = businessTableForCategories('xzqpehc234ajdpa8')`.

How can I insert new data into that nested table for that entry in Category without removing the entry, or losing the data stored in the nested table?

I ask because one of the entries I am trying to insert requires an insert statement that is 25137 characters long, which is way past Oracle's limit for a single command. This is because there are many businesses in the category. I would like to create the category, and then insert the businesses one by one (or maybe small groupings) into the nested table "businesses".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MULTISET UNION [ALL|DISTINCT]` operator:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a9348f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE businessTableForCategories AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(128);
/

CREATE TABLE Category (
name                    VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
businesses              businessTableForCategories
) NESTED TABLE businesses STORE AS categoryBusinessTable
/

INSERT INTO Category VALUES (
  'Restaurant',
  businessTableForCategories('xzqpehc234ajdpa8')
)
/

UPDATE Category
SET businesses = businesses
                 MULTISET UNION ALL 
                 businessTableForCategories('other_value')
WHERE name = 'Restaurant'
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   category
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a9348f/2/0)**:

```
|       NAME |                   BUSINESSES |
|------------|------------------------------|
| Restaurant | xzqpehc234ajdpa8,other_value |
```

**Query 2**:

Or use a bind variable to include the collection in the query:

```
DECLARE
  businesses businessTableForCategories := businessTableForCategories();
BEGIN
  businesses.EXTEND( 10000 );
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10000 LOOP
    businesses(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'x', 128 );
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO Category VALUES ( 'lots of data', businesses );
END;
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT name, CARDINALITY( businesses )
FROM   Category
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a9348f/2/2)**:

```
|         NAME | CARDINALITY(BUSINESSES) |
|--------------|-------------------------|
| lots of data |                   10000 |
|   Restaurant |                       2 |
```