# How to update/insert values in nested table of values while preserving existing values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, custom-type

In our Oracle 11g database, I have a custom data type:

num_list

```
create or replace type
    num_list
as
    table of varchar2(25);
```

I then created a table that uses this datatype:

```
create table num_list_table(
    id number(*,0)
    ,numbers num_list
) nested table numbers store as numbers_tab
;
```

I then inserted the following rows:

```
insert into num_list_table values (1, num_list('123', 456'));
```

And I now have 1 row. I'm trying to figure out how to insert more values into the num_list of row 1 while preserving any existing values and without having to manually type those existing values; this is a small example of a much larger task that will require mass updates while preserving vals).

I get close with this:

```
update
    num_list_table
set numbers = (select num_list(numbers) from (
    select listagg(numbers, ',') within group (order by numbers) numbers
    from (select t.column_value numbers
          from 
              num_list_table nlt,
              table(nlt.numbers) t
           where
               st.id = 1
         union
         select '789'
         from dual)))
     where id = 1;
```

However, these results are a single entry:

```
num_list('123,456,789')
```

I need them to be multiple entries in the num_list:

```
num_list('123', '456', '789')
```

Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to insert a value into a nested table without losing data in that table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151721/how-to-insert-a-value-into-a-nested-table-without-losing-data-in-that-table)

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a single value into nested table to a specific ID, like this:

```
insert into table 
       (select numbers 
          from num_list_table 
          where id = 1)
values ('123')
```

or using insert select:

```
insert into table 
       (select numbers 
          from num_list_table 
         where id = 1)
select n.same_type_field
  from another_table n;
```